# Saved search in NetSuite returning multiple lines for each vendor bill despite Main Line is True in criteria

Tags: sql, netsuite

I am creating a performance metrics report for our AP Team. They want to see processing dates for vendor bills from received to approved and every point in between so they can see where bottlenecks are occurring and the like, along with the user/approver doing each step. We have an approval workflow in place that routes the vendor bills through first and second approvals. There are also likely to be rejections that also need to be captured.

These are the columns we envision the search to have with one vendor bill per row. The most recent date at each stage should be pulled so, if the bill has to be routed back for corrections and then submitted for approval again, there would still only be one line per vendor bill.

Subsidiary | Transaction Status | Date Received | Date Processed | Processed By | Date Submitted for First Approval | Name | Date Submitted for Second Approval | Name | Date Approved | Name | Date if Rejected | Name|

I currently have the following in the results of a Transaction Saved Search. [I have omitted columns that are irrelevant to my question.] My problem is that the search is returning multiple lines per document number, one line for each instance of the date. In other words, the First Vendor Approval date and Name is on one line then the First Subsidiary Approval date and Name is on the next line, etc. **What am I missing that will get the results to show on one line per document number?** Let me know if you need additional information.

| FIELD | FORMULA |
| --- | --- |
| Document Number |  |
| Type |  |
| Subsidiary |  |
| Name [Vendor] |  |
| Vendor Bill Date |  |
| Due Date |  |
| Approval Status |  |
| Date Created |  |
| Created By |  |
| Formula (Date/Time) | CASE WHEN {workflowhistory.stateinfo} = 'Pending First Vendor Approval' THEN {workflowhistory.dateenteredstate} END |
| Formula (Text) | CASE WHEN {workflowhistory.stateinfo} = 'Pending First Vendor Approval' THEN {systemnotes.name} END |
| Formula (Date/Time) | CASE WHEN {workflowhistory.stateinfo} = 'Pending First Subsidiary Approval' THEN {workflowhistory.dateenteredstate} END |
| Formula (Text) | CASE WHEN {workflowhistory.stateinfo} = 'Pending First Subsidiary Approval' THEN {systemnotes.name} END |
| Formula (Date/Time) | CASE WHEN {workflowhistory.stateinfo} = 'Approved' THEN {workflowhistory.dateenteredstate} END |
| Formula (Text) | CASE WHEN {workflowhistory.stateinfo} = 'Approved' THEN {systemnotes.name} END |
| Formula (Date/Time) | CASE WHEN {workflowhistory.stateinfo} = 'Rejected' THEN {workflowhistory.dateenteredstate} END |
| Formula (Text) | CASE WHEN {workflowhistory.stateinfo} = 'Rejected' THEN {systemnotes.name} END |

This is the Criteria I have set.

| PARENS | FILTER | DESCRIPTION | FORMULA | PARENS | AND/OR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Type | is any of Bill, Bill Credit |  |  | And |
|  | Main Line | is true |  |  | And |
|  | Date Created | is not before 1/1/2021 |  |  | And |
| ( | Formula (Text) | is 1 | CASE WHEN {workflowhistory.stateinfo} = 'Pending First Vendor Approval' THEN '1' END |  | Or |
|  | Formula (Text) | is 2 | CASE WHEN {workflowhistory.stateinfo} = 'Pending First Subsidiary Approval' THEN '2' END |  | Or |
|  | Formula (Text) | is 3 | CASE WHEN {workflowhistory.stateinfo} = 'Approved' THEN '3' END |  | Or |
|  | Formula (Text) | is 4 | CASE WHEN {workflowhistory.stateinfo} = 'Rejected' THEN '4' END | ) |  |

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can offer!

Answer (score 0):

The work flow history record join causes the results to have more than one line per transaction.

You may be able to fix that by storing the various work flow fields either on the workflow or on the transaction and then you'd include only the current workflow (or just the tran fields) so that you were not referencing the workflow history records in the search.

Comment: Are you talking about adding custom fields to the transaction form that point to the workflow fields? Thank you for your response!

Comment: not quite. I meant adding fields to the transaction that the workflow sets with "Set Field Value" actions as diferent stages are reached.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that a single result (Vendor Bill or Credit) could have multiple instances of where "workflowhistory.stateinfo" equals for example "Approved" (or one of the other 3 options you're trying to isolate)? This could be true if the workflow is set to be triggered by anything besides record create (which is the only mode guaranteed to happen only once).  Essentially you're getting multiple lines for 1 transaction because there are columns where the values between the two search result lines are different.  Check your results to see where this is true in the UI.  If there aren't any differences in the UI between two or more result lines for 1 transaction **try grouping your results**.  Use the "Summary Group" on the results tab of the saved search.  Reference [Suite Answer Id: 8423](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/8423/kw/summary%20results)

Comment: It is possible that there are legitimately multiple results. That's why I stated in my op that I'd like to pull the most recent of each stage. I did try grouping the results and it resulted in a single line for the entire report. I will look at the SuiteAnswer you tagged and see if that helps me. Appreciate the response.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was able to solve my issue by using the Group function on all header type lines and then Minimum/Maximum on the dates. I had previously tried to Group only on the Document Number and use the Maximum function on the date lines but that had resulted in one line for the entire report and omitted the columns that didn't have grouping. Thank you to those that left answers for me.